# How do I populate a select list in jQuery with data from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, list, select, populate

I have a bunch of courses and each course has a different number of lessons. So, I have two select lists one for courses and one for the lessons associated with that course. The course select list is easy, I'm doing that from the back end of PHP in a foreach loop. I'm going through all the courses that a student has:

```
public function createContent($student)
{
//get student courses
//get lessons of each course
//get the upcoming lessons
 $lessons = $this->getLessons($courses); //need to make use of $lessons to populate lesson list

        foreach($courseArray as $c)
        {               
            $courseSelectList .= '<option id="select"'.$count.' value="'.$c['id'].'">'.$c['fullname'].'</option>';
            $count++;           
        }
//create a Lesson select list in php backend or do it in the front end dynamically with jQuery?
        return $courseSelectList.$lessonSelectList;
}
```

My next step is to create a second select list that contains the lessons of the selected course. How this list is populated depends on what the student selects in the course select list. All this is dynamic and depends on the student so the courses (and thus the lessons) in the course select list is different for each student and is retrieved from the database. Given the student and course, I know which lessons should be in the lesson select list. The lessons are retrieved after I first retrieve the courses of the student as shown in the comments in the code below. I just need a way to populate the lesson select list according to what the student selects.

How should I go about doing this? Any help would be great. Bear in mind I'm a beginner jQuery user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to issue an AJAX request based upon the value of the selected course.  I am assuming below that the id of the course select is 'courseSelect':

```
$('#courseSelect').bind('change', function() {
    var _t = $(this);
    var val = _t.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/script.php',
        data: 'c='+val,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#lessonSelect').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

The strategy behind this is that your 'script.php' is called once a different option is selected for the courses.  'script.php' will be sent the value of the option by the browser and can be accessed as `$_GET['c']`.  The success function will be called once the request returns, and the html parameter will be set equal to *everything that you output inside of script.php* (via `echo`, `print`, error statements issued by PHP, *all* output).

In this sense your script.php will simply select the list of lessons from your database for the given course, and just output all of the `<option value = 'Lesson Key'>Lesson</option>` markup.  Since the output of the server-side script is HTML markup, I named the parameter to the success function *html*.

**script.php**

```
<?php
    // Validate existence and proper type of input variable
    // I am assuming here that the 'value' for the option for each course is an
    // integer primary key for a table in your database
    if(!isset($_GET['c']) || !is_numeric($_GET['c']))
        exit();
   $course = intval( $_GET['c'] );
   // Select all of the lessons for the selected course from your database 
   // and output them as HTML Option elements.
?>
```

Comment: Hey, that's one of my problems. Everywhere I look is calling a php file that is sequential. All my files are classes with methods in them. Would I really have to create a separate file just for this?

Comment: If you already have a method in place for getting some sort of data structure containing the lessons and their keys given a class key, then no.  It depends on the structure of your classes and how you handle requests. Do you use a front end controller? If so, do you have a facility for detecting AJAX requests and dispatching them?  If you answer no, then you will either have to change the way you handle requests or make a separate PHP file.

Comment: For your $_GET['c'] are you refering to the course ID which is set in the option values?

'<option id="select"'.$count.' value="'.$c['id'].'">'

I think I'm just going to create a new file. Seems like the easiest solution.

Actually, what would I name 'c' as, how would I refer to the value of the selected option in php in the GET variable?

Comment: If you look at the jQuery code, you can see it is appending `'c='+val`.  This is where you define what the GET variable's name would be.  The `val` variable is being set to the current value of the course select option, so this is what is being sent to PHP.

Comment: I'm just going to copy and paste the jQuery code and hopefully it should all work. I haven't a clue about ajax!! I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: The best thing I can do at this point is just to point you to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Given that my PHP code is like this `   foreach($courseArray as $c)
   {    
    $courseSelectList .= '<option id="select"'.$count.' value="'.$c['id'].'">'.$c['fullname'].'</option>';
    $count++;   
   }
    
   $divLessonSelect = '<div id="lessonSelectContainer"></div>';
   $courseSelectList .= $divLessonSelect;`

How do I insert the lesson select list into the div container after a succesful ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful and simple jQuery plugin,

http://codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/

Comment: This link includes both the PHP and javascript code you need to make it work, pretty solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the simplest way to do it (from a jQ point of view, at least) is to call [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and generate the HTML on the server side.

For example, lets say that you existing PHP code generates the following HTML:

```
<select id="select_1">
  <option value="0">Please select...</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<div id="container_for_select_2"></div>
```

Now we attach a `change` event to this select, and load the next select into the container `<div>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#select_1").change(function() {

    // Get the value of the option that was chosen
    // You could also do: var currentValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var currentValue = $(this).val();

    // Don't do anything if the "Please select" option was chosen
    if (currentValue == '0') {
      return;
    }

    // Load some data from the server into the next <div>
    $("#container_for_select_2").load('getselect.php?option='+currentValue);

  });

</script>
```

So now, in `getselect.php` we can do something like this:

```
<?php

  switch ($_GET['option']) {
    case 1:
      echo '<select><option value="1">An option</option><option value="2">Another option</option></select>';
      break;
    case 2:
      echo '<select><option value="3">An option</option><option value="4">Another option</option></select>';
      break;

    // ...etc...

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the code for you, from a very high level this is how i would do it without plugins:
create a page that returns a list of your lessons from a database or wherever they are stored, based on which course id is passed to it.
create a javascript (or jquery) ajax method on your page that passes your course id to this page and clears and creates the lessons dropdown from the returned data (JSON format is good for the returned data). Call the ajax method whenever the change event is fired on your course dropdown.
look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: How would I refer to a method in the php class file in ajax?

Comment: include you class in a serving page, have the page call your class methods and output the results. The ajax on your calling page basically works like a normal request, and the data which the serving page writes out is the data that the ajax method on your calling page will receive

Comment: Is there no other way around this other than creating a new php file deliberately for ajax?

Comment: I primarily use asp.net web services to supply the data. You could use the php equivalent, but this is much more complex and you need it installed on the server. http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php. If I was building a little php app like this, it would be a page for sure.

Comment: something you can do to avoid adding in a new page is to build the functionality into your existing calling page, which you can then call from itself with a querystring or posted data